When do I know if i should delete or keep a variable for a fraud detection model?
I am quite new to data analysis and this is my first attempt to try and make a model for fraud detection. Based on the graph I made during the exploratory data analysis (EDA) I am very unsure wheter I should drop the variable "MonthClaimed" and keep "Month" or if i should keep both they seem to show pretty much the same. Except that "MonthClamied" is consistently lower in my logic this is due to some insurance claims being rejected either because it is actual fraud or they do not live up the insurance firms’ requirements.
So my question is should i delete MonthClaimed and why or should i keep it and why based on my exploratory data analysis
MonthClaimed: The month in which the insurance claim was processed.
Month: The month in which the insurance claim was made.
Image of counts of my two variables
Thank you for your help beforehand
Not really code related
